# Data Access Management - Best practices in AD env

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to collect some info, preferably in form of whitepaper or 'best practices manual', on the topic of data management access in large organizations.

I work in on of those, the file structure is extremely complicated and it's becoming more and more challenging to manage access requests to certain folders. Data owners, ACLs inheritance, folder structure etc.

Any suggestions please, online resources or books that you know of?

Thanks
Luka

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, found a good part of what I was searching for in:

Windows Administration Resource Kit: Productivity Solutions for IT Professionals

and some of that in the Technet database under Data Managment.

If anydody else has any other sources, please share.